# How to use variables from Azure variable group, when creating MariaDB docker image?

Tags: azure, docker, variables, pipeline

We use a docker image of a MariaDB database dump in our integration tests.

We use Azure pipeline to create the docker image.
The docker file is as follows:

```
FROM mariadb:10.4.26

ENV MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD <some>
ENV MARIADB_USER <some>
ENV MARIADB_PASSWORD <some>
ENV MARIADB_DATABASE <some>

COPY ./.pipelines/dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

EXPOSE 3306
```

and the steps in the yaml file of the pipeline are like this:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Login to ACR
  inputs:
    command: login
    containerRegistry: ${{ parameters.dockerRegistryServiceConnection }}

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
  inputs:
    # Only build on PR, and build and push docker image otherwise
    ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest') }}:
      command: build
    ${{ else }}:
      command: buildAndPush
    repository: ${{ parameters.imageRepository }}
    dockerfile: ${{ parameters.dockerfilePath }}
    buildContext: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    containerRegistry: ${{ parameters.dockerRegistryServiceConnection }}
    tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
```

It works fine, but now we have put the MARIADB variables into an Azure variable group and would like to read the variable values from there, when creating the docker image.

I know the following:

1. How to read values from Azure variable group..and put it into some env variable:

```
$db=az pipelines variable-group variable list --group-id <some_group_id> --output json
echo "$db"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=allvars]$db"
```

2.I see from here, that i have to use --build-args, and also divide the steps into "build" and "push":
https://markmcgookin.com/2021/06/14/using-build-args-with-docker-in-azure-devops-pipelines/

and i still have to figure out how:

1. To use the variables in Azure variable group as build-args arguments - for example if the   user property in the variable group is named "DB_USER" and the password property in the variable is named "DB_PASSWORD", should i use something like this:

--build-arg user=$(allvars.DB_USER), password = $(allvars.DB_PASSWORD)

2. How in the docker file to use the values, that are passed as arguments? Is it something like this?

```
FROM mariadb:10.4.26

ENV MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD <some>
ENV MARIADB_USER $(user)
ENV MARIADB_PASSWORD $(password)
ENV MARIADB_DATABASE <some>

COPY ./.pipelines/dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

EXPOSE 3306
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `arguments` input in your [Docker@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml) task, something like below would work:

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: 'Build the image'
  inputs:
    ...
    arguments: --build-arg "user=${{DB_USER}}" --build-arg "password=${{DB_PASSWORD}}"
```

Where `DB_USER` and `DB_PASSWORD` should be available as pipeline variables or in the ADO Variable groups